# one select does not work for another, oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

so my code is:

```
select max(SERIAL_NBR) AS RESULT from ttr_voucher
where voucher_typcode = 'VOUCHER' AND SERIAL_NBR LIKE '24%'
```

In result I get one column with max serialNBR and everything is ok, then I would like to get only first a few chars od result, I know I have to use

```
SUBSTR(SERIAL_NBR, 1, 3)
```

But in result when i apply my changes I receive two columns:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SERIAL_NBR, 1, 3),
(select max(SERIAL_NBR) AS RESULT from ttr_voucher
where voucher_typcode = 'VOUCHER' AND SERIAL_NBR LIKE '24%') 
FROM ttr_voucher
```

In the code above "AS RESULT" os not working.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wInYh.png)

How to connect two selects one with getting max serial nbr with where and another getting only first 3 chars of this max serial number?

Comment: You have to check the syntax first. There are two unrelated queries and two output expressions in the main query. That's why you receive two columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(X.result, 1, 3)from
(
    select max(SERIAL_NBR) AS RESULT from ttr_voucher
    where voucher_typcode = 'VOUCHER' AND SERIAL_NBR LIKE '24%'
) X
```